# How to plot rosenbrock function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, plot

I'm trying to plot `rosenbrock function`

[Rosenbrock Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpo1O.png)

like this

```
clear; clc; close all;
% Parameters
nx = 2;                 % No. of Input variables
f = @rosenbrock;
limits = repmat([-10 10], nx, 1);
titl = 'Rosenbrock';

% Plot
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(limits(1,1),limits(1,2),100),...
                 linspace(limits(2,1),limits(2,2),100));

Z = reshape(f([X(:)'; Y(:)']), 100, 100);

surfc(X,Y,Z);
```

`rosenbrock.m`

```
function [y] = rosenbrock(x)
    xn = circshift(x',1)';
    xn(1) = 0;
    y = sum(100*(xn - x.^2).^2 + (x - 1).^2);
end
```

I know the above function implementation is not correct. With loop it can be easily done, but with vectorization I'm getting wrong results. Can any body help.

[Rosenbrock](https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/rosen.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vectorized version of [`rosenbrock function`](https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/Code/rosenm.html) would be -

```
sum(100*(xx(2:end) - xx(1:end-1).^2).^2 + (xx(1:end-1)-1).^2)
```

Sample run -

```
% Input array
>> xx   
xx =
     5     1     3     9     2     8     5     9     1     4

% Loopy implementation
>> d = length(xx);  
sum1 = 0;
for ii = 1:(d-1)
    xi = xx(ii);
    xnext = xx(ii+1);
    new = 100*(xnext-xi^2)^2 + (xi-1)^2;
    sum1 = sum1 + new;
end
y = sum1;
>> y
y =
     1698514

% Vectorized implementation
>> sum(100*(xx(2:end) - xx(1:end-1).^2).^2 + (xx(1:end-1)-1).^2)
ans =
     1698514
```

Comment: With your code, I'm getting this error while calling reshape function. `To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.`

Comment: @KarenJohnson Well, I am not using `reshape`. So, I am not sure how you are using my code. Also, I am assuming that function is outputting a scalar, just like with the loopy implementation.

Comment: @KarenJohnson Is the linked loopy code the one applicable in your case? Why not share the loopy code that works for you, then we can vectorize it?

Comment: I'm using my above code as it is. I have just changed the rosenbrock function
http://paste.ofcode.org/hinzGLy6C3UPJ2xSfnN3XQ

Comment: @KarenJohnson But you said in the question that your code is not correct. Do you have a loopy implementation that is correct/works? If you have, could you share that?

Comment: Here is the loopy implementation I was using. https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/Code/rosenm.html
but it is also giving the same error.

Comment: @KarenJohnson Well I am not familiar with the science behind `rosenbrock`, so I can't help you formulating it.  Let me know if you come across a working version loopy or otherwise. Also you mentioned in the question - `"With loop it can be easily done"`. So, why not implement a loopy version? :)

Comment: Actually for high dimensional data loopy implementation will be slow as compared to vectorize implementation. So, in matlab always try to vectorize your equation.

Comment: @KarenJohnson Forget about performance, get a working loopy code and then vectorize it.

Comment: With loopy implementation also I'm getting same error while calling reshape function `To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change`